# Wordpress rewrite a url

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite `http://website.com/?slug=product_info.php&products_id=32` to `http://website.com/product_info/32` and I use this code,

```
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array','wp_insertMyRewriteRules');
add_filter('query_vars','wp_insertMyRewriteQueryVars'); 


// Adding a new rule
function wp_insertMyRewriteRules($rules)
{
    $newrules = array();
    $newrules['(product_info)/(\d*)$'] = 'index.php?pagename=store&slug=product_info.php&products_id=$matches[1]';
    return $newrules + $rules;
}

// Adding the bid var so that WP recognizes it
function wp_insertMyRewriteQueryVars($vars)
{
    array_push($vars, 'products_id');
    return $vars;
}
```

I also used this code,

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse41778_add_rewrite' );
function wpse41778_add_rewrite()
{
    add_rewrite_tag('%products_id%','([^/]+)');
    add_rewrite_tag('%slug%','([^/]+)');
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^product_info/([^/]+)/?$', 
        'index.php?pagename=store&slug=product_info.php&products_id=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
```

I have manually flushed the rules but when i go to `http://website.com/product_info/32` it went to `http://website.com` instead of the product page. Both of the codes have this kind of issue.

Here is the contents of my .htaccess,

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^login$ /wp-login.php [L]
RewriteRule ^signup$ /wp-signup.php [L]
RewriteRule ^register$ /wp-register.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

I don't know whats the problem and Im actually newbie on this. Please help.

Comment: I don't think this is going to solve your problem but you should use `products_id=$matches[2]` in your rewrite rule

Comment: tried but still no success. Can u suggest another solution if my code cannot really work?

Comment: Yes. Actually, when i go to `http://website.com/index.php?pagename=store&slug=product_info.php&products_id=32` it goes to the correct product page.

Comment: what does your .htaccess looks like?

Comment: Please see my updated post above.

Comment: your rule obviously does not appear here, this means the rewrite rules were not properly flushed

Comment: the .htaccess and the WP internal rewrites are two different things

Comment: @pkyeck do you have a solution for this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rules are not flushed, add this code to flush them automatically:

```
add_action('wp_loaded', 'my_flush_rules');

// flush_rules() if our rules are not yet included
function my_flush_rules(){
    $rules = get_option('rewrite_rules');

    if (!isset($rules['(product_info)/(\d*)$'])) {
        global $wp_rewrite;
        $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
    }
}
```

and make sure your .htaccess file is writable by Wordpress

Comment: make sure you use the same regex everywhere, because I noticed you were using two different ones in `wp_insertMyRewriteRules` and `wpse41778_add_rewrite`